# Get exit status of the parent's last command

Tags: linux, bash, parent, exit

If I have a bash script that looks like this:

```
some_command
. some_bash
```

And `some_bash` that looks like this:

```
if [ "$?" != "0" ]
then
 do_something
else
 do_something_else
fi
```

I would expect that, `some_bash`, being executed in the parent's environment (`.`), would get the exit status (`$?`) of parent's `some_command`. But it doesn't. Im guessing it is getting an exit status of successfully calling itself, which is always true.

Is there any way to bypass this, other than `some_bash $?`and `if [ "$1" != "0" ]`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. The sourced script gets the exit code of the previous command, as I would expect. (The `.` command cannot exit before `some_bash` finishes, since *its* exit status is supposed to be that of the script it sources.)

Comment: I triple-checked to confirm, I put `echo $?` at the very beginning of the sourced script, and tried putting `true` and `false` just before I call it. It always gets `0`, no mater if it's `. `'ed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider passing the value to the command:

```
some_command
. some_bash "$?"

if [[ $1 -ne 0 ]]; then
```

Although it would replace any positional parameter that currently exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function instead of a script and use it:

```
foo() {
  if [ "$?" != "0" ]
  then
    do_something
  else
    do_something_else
  fi
}

some_command
foo
```

You can define foo in some script, say script.sh. Then you can use it like:

```
. script.sh
some_command
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You could export the exit status:

```
some_command
export LASTRETURN=$?
. some_bash
```

Inside some_bash you can use

```
${LASTRETURN}
```